# What is Exception severity in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

I saw this code in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorexception.getseverity.php):

```
try {
throw new ErrorException("Exception message", 0, E_USER_ERROR);
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
echo "This exception severity is: " . $e->getSeverity();
var_dump($e->getSeverity() === E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

And it continues:

```
This exception severity is: 256
bool(true)
```

What does exception severity mean, and do I have to use it at all?

Answer (score 3):

The `$severity` is an integer representing, well, the severity of the error thrown. The manual states that it can be any integer, but it's preferable to use a constant from the [predefined error constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). These are the same used by [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

Notice that `ErrorException` extends `Exception`, adding the `$severity` parameter. This is because `ErrorException` is normally used to convert the normal errors PHP shows into `Exception`s. This is done via [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

So, the `ErrorException::$severity` is really the **severity of the PHP error that would have been shown if you hadn't thrown it as an `Exception`.** You can use it to decide what to do when you catch an `ErrorException` depending on what caused it.

Comment: So `severity` basically is the [type of error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) to report.